# Cucumber Test Cannot find field when its there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, erb

While I was writing cucumber test code,
I get:

```
Unable to find field "username" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

But I have the following on the page itself.

```
<%= f.text_field :username, :placeholder => "Username" %>
```

I've checked that it lands on the correct page using

```
save_and_open_page
fill_in "username", :with => "TESTUSER"
```

isn't the tag :username? What am I supposed to write instead?

Comment: are you sure about the `locator` it is 'username' r8?

Comment: Check your html - it should match on either id, name or label of the field.

Comment: @GraemeMcLean absolutely r8......

Comment: The HTML I'm using is the 2nd line. The f.text_field. I thought the :username will give it a tag named username no?

Comment: The second line above is erb code used to generate html - it's not actually html.  The username field will have an id and name reflecting the model (e.g. user_username for the id, or user[username] for the name).  View your code in a browser and do view source to see what it actually puts there.

Comment: Oh I see. But how do I change it then, or set another name/id for it? Also I don't understand the need for this reflection of the model (I'm an old school php-er trying to grasp craptonnes of rails frontend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capybara will match fields based on their id, name or label text.  See [here](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_field?-instance_method) for more details.

Since you are using the default text_field helper, id and name will default to include the model (e.g. `user_username` for the id, or `user[username]` for the name).  You *can* change these defaults by simply using `id: <id>` or `name: <name>` on your `text_field` call but you might run into other problems later - so probably best to stay with the defaults.

Change your capybara test to `fill_in "user_username"` or `fill_in "user[username]"` to make it match.  Alternatively, if you have a `label_for` on the field, you can match on the text of the label which can make your tests more readable.

Comment: Thank you so much! One other question, for capy tests is there a fill_in "a" or "b" kind of code? I want it to fill fields that say something along the same lines like if the form asks for name twice, but in two different names/ids.

Comment: You mean fill both fields at the same time?  I don't know of anything - I would just target each field separately using it's id or name since that is unique.

Comment: Oh. Ok that works too. I was writing cucumber tests that could be reused lol. I thought that was the point of rails.